# How to disable caching in Mojolicious::Lite app

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

currently i added this line to Mojolicious::Lite app to disable caching

```
app->renderer->cache->max_keys(0);
```

but sometimes webpage showing updated content and sometimes showing cached template

i do not know exactly what the problem is, there is no problem with morbo, this is happening only with hypnotoad. i want to try disabling the cache.

edit: i solved my problem. problem is not with the mojolicious caching, it is with the database caching. if you experience similar problem, try setting 'AutoCommit' to 1 in your DBI->connect() method.

Comment: Could it be the browser cache? Try pressing ctrl+shift+supr and deleting it.

Comment: @sergiotarxz i tried that.

Comment: @sergiotarxz when i restart hypnotoad it is showing updated content. i think problem is with caching

Comment: Then I don't know what can be happening, I am a novice with Mojolicious.

Comment: I remember a question about caching in Mojo. Let me find it for you.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750243/1331451. I wrote a new cache plugin https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::Renderer::WithoutCache to solve it, and then had a long discussion with Mojo author SRI about the uselessness of it. He couldn't fathom someone wanting this.