# How can I keep Mojolicious from caching static files?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

For development purposes I would like morbo NOT to cache any static files.

Is that doable? how?

Thanks -

Comment: It looks like https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-8.42/lib/Mojo/Server/Morbo/Backend/Poll.pm is implementing that. You could make your own backend, copy that code and get rid of the cache I guess. But I might be wrong and this is about the code files that it uses to reload the app. Do you mean static files as in CSS that it serves directly?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41750243/1331451

Comment: @simbabque - yes, I mean CSS files and similar (in my case vue components)